# How to get number of rows, of several tables from a view file

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my schema there are several tables, let's say, t1, t2, t3.

I want to create a simple statistics page for the **admin** of the page, like displaying the number of rows of each of the tables at a generic view file.

I know that with SQL this is really simple like:
`select count(*) from t1;`

But how can I go about doing this from a view file?

Also, do you think this is an efficient way to do that (regarding that it's for the admin page which will not be used *that much*)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing every table corresponds to a model class. You can view the results of:

```
TableOneModel.count
TableTwoModel.count
TableThreeModel.count
```

Comment: I don't suggest doing this in a view. While this is possible, the view should have no knowledge of the model. This should be done in a controller and saved as some variable to be displayed in the view.